# PageVisibility HTML5 API on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, visibility

I checked [caniuse for pagevisibility support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility) and it states that Safari supports it.

However, my Pagevisibility implementation does not work on Safari 9. It works everywhere else.

See below:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if (document.hidden) {     
     function1();
  } else {
     function2();
  } 
});
```

Is there a specific way to code (JS) PageVisbility in Safari?

Comment: @Stephan Do you really think that [tag:caniuse] is useful at all? Will people go searching for questions under that tag? Also when you edit questions, make sure you fix EVERYTHING in that post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var visibilityHidden, visibilityChange;
    // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        visibilityHidden = "hidden";
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
        visibilityHidden = "mozHidden";
        visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        visibilityHidden = "msHidden";
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        visibilityHidden = "webkitHidden";
        visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
    }

    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
      if (document[visibilityHidden]) {     
         function1();
      } else {
         function2();
      } 
    });
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: visibilityChange variable should be used, this code is not working.

Comment: I fixed the error in the code.  In my tests this appears to work on Safari and others.