# How do I automatically redirect or close an inactive tab on iPhone?

Tags: javascript

I have a website that I want to automatically close or redirect if the user tabs away. I have an event listener that listens for visibility and redirects if the tab is inactive.

```
const visibilityChange = ...logic for msvisibilitychange | webkitvisibilitychange | visibilitychange...
const hidden =  ... logic for msHidden | webkitHidden | hidden ...

window.addEventListener(visibilityChange, (event) => {
    if (hidden) {
       window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')
    }
})
```

On desktop, everything works as expected on both Chrome and Safari...  that is, if  I open up the webpage on my laptop and then open up another tab, this works as expected.

However, on mobile, Chrome behaves as expected, but Safari does not.  The event listener doesn't appear to fire at all if I open up the site and then open up a different tab on my phone.

How can I enforce my desired behavior on mobile Safari?

This is NOT identical to this question ([PageVisibility HTML5 API on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748106/pagevisibility-html5-api-on-safari)), because this works perfectly fine on Safari on desktop, and I'm also checking for the different browser event name variations.

Comment: Please include code that people can test themselves. Your pseudocode does not allow this.

Comment: Just in case your other question was deleted before you resolved the issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74219010/retrieve-sum-result-from-psql-using-raw-query-with-gorm @oddnumberedcat