# Retrieve sum() result from psql using raw query with Gorm

Tags: sql, go, psql, go-gorm, dbeaver

My raw query is

```
SELECT 
  at."category" AS "category", 
  at."month" AS "month", 
  sum(at.price_aft_discount) as "sum", 
  sum(at.qty_ordered) as "sum2" 
FROM 
  all_trans at 
GROUP BY 
  at."category", 
  at."month" 
ORDER BY 
  at."category" ASC, 
  at."month" asc
```

When executing above query in DBeaver, the sum columns give warning: `sum: numeric(131089,0) (Read-only: No corresponding table column)`. Same warning is given for `sum2`

My code to query save the result in Go using Gorm is:

```
type ATQueryResult struct {
   category string  `gorm:"column:category"`
   month    string  `gorm:"column:month"`
   sum      float32 `gorm:"column:sum"`
   sum2     float32 `gorm:"column:sum2"`
}

queryString := ... // same as above
var result []ATQueryResult

db.Table(model.TableAllTrans).Raw(queryString).Find(&result)

fmt.Println(result[3])
```

But the issue is, all `result[i].sum` and `result[i].sum2` is `0-zero`. I can see the actual sum number (which is all non-zero) when querying live on DBeaver, albeit with the above warning. But when I tried to scan the query result on to `result`, all the sum values are 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields must be [exported](https://golangbyexample.com/exported-unexported-fields-struct-go/) for gorm (or whatever it leverages under the hood) to be able to populate them. Try using:

```
type ATQueryResult struct {
    Category string  `gorm:"column:category"`
    Month    string  `gorm:"column:month"`
    Sum      float32 `gorm:"column:sum"`
    Sum2     float32 `gorm:"column:sum2"`
}
```

Comment: I realized this just a moment ago. Thanks! That was definitely stupid of me.